# ZF2 composer usage to install new module

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am facing some problems with using the composer to install ZF2 components.

I do know how to work with ZF2 but now I want to make user of composer to get modules
into my existing project much easier than download them by zip.

I find out how to build a new project by composer:

```
composer create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application --stability dev
```

after I rename the skeleton-application to my project name.

OK, my issue. I would like to install the ZcfBase module by composer but I get the follow problems;

I added the composer value of the project into my own composer;

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*"
    },

    "name": "zf-commons/zfc-base",
    "description": "A set of genetic (abstract) classes which are commonly used across multiple modules.",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": [
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Evan Coury",
            "email": "me@evancoury.com",
            "homepage": "http://blog.evan.pro/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kyle Spraggs",
            "email": "theman@spiffyjr.me",
            "homepage": "http://www.spiffyjr.me/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zend-db": "~2.1",
        "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "~2.1",
        "zendframework/zend-loader": "~2.1",
        "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "~2.1",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.1",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "~2.1",
        "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ZfcBase": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "./Module.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

I run the 'composer update' and after 'composer install' which returns into:

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                
  Could not scan for classes inside "./Module.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

My structure of the vendor is a bit strange too in my eyes;

[image]

I am used to this structure (without using composer)

[image]

Hope someone can give me a turn in the right way by how to configure it in the right way.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your command in `/var/www/`:

```
composer create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application --stability dev
```

creates a folder: `/var/www/skeleton-application/`

All you need to do is:

Go into this folder:

```
cd /var/www/skeleton-application/
```

And install the ZfcBase module:

```
composer.phar require zf-commons/zfc-base:dev-master
```

This is equivalent to: `[project_name]:branch`.

In order to find the project name for other modules, go into their composer.json and check 'name': https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/composer.json

Hope this  helps!

Comment: Yes this is hope full and made the working process of composer all clear to me! :) Many thanks!